# Fedora | how to restore iptables from specific file on boot

Tags: centos, iptables, redhat, fedora

I need to make ip-tables persistent on my machines.
I was able to do it on Debian based systems by creating the following file which runs when my network is up:

**/etc/network/if-up.d/run-iptables**

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

I tried to do the same on Fedora based systems (CentOS, RHEL, Fedore...) using the following file:
**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup**
but unfourtantly it doesn't work.

any ideas on how to perform this without using any additional service?

Thank you

Comment: do you have rc.local file under /etc/rc.local path? it depends on your Fedora version. If yes, then place your script in this file. any script in this file will be executed during boot.

Comment: that solved my problem, please write it as an answer and mention tha rc-local.service needs to be active :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use rc.local file under `/etc/rc.local` path.

Just make sure that rc.local file is executable :
Run the following command to check whether file /etc/rc.local is executable:

```
ls -l /etc/rc.local
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 419 2022-03-07 11:26 /etc/rc.local
```

Traditionally, the shell script /etc/rc.local used by developers and Linux sysadmin to call other scripts or commands after all services are loaded. Typically /etc/rc.local get called at the end when Linux init switched to a multiuser runlevel.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the correct file to make it persistent is:

> /etc/sysconfig/iptables

This according to [the documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-IPTables-Saving_IPTables_Rules.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but didn't solve what i was ask for, since it's require to install iptables-services / iptables-persistent